# Pandas - change format of pivoted table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe with columns A B C D E F.

I want to pivot column B (which has 2 possible values) so the final result looks like this:

```
              B (value 1)                B (value 2)
              C  D  E  F                 C  D  E  F
```

A(index)

For that, I have tried this code:

df.pivot(index=A, columns=B, values=[C, D, E, F])

However, instead of looking like this, my pivoted DF looks as follows:

```
              C                   D                    E                   F               
     B(value1) B(value2  B(value1) B(value2)  B(value1) B(value2) B(value1) B(value2)
```

A(index)

Do you know how I could reorganise the data so it looks the way I need it?

Thank you in advance!

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUW79.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df.pivot(index=A, columns=B, values=[C, D, E, F]).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```